# Decoding RC transmitter data

Tags: remote-control

I would like to use my FSi6 transmitter but not the receiver that comes with it (I´m trying to save weight), for that I was planning to get one of this NRF24L01 breakout boards. The problem is, how do you interpret the incoming traffic? After some googling, I couldn´t find any information from flysky.

I would think that this is a common thing to do, as you could pair the transmitter with another receiver (perhaps other brand) so there must be a standard protocol.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: why do you think that the FSi6 can communicate with the NRF24L01?

Comment: I expect that as both use 2.4 it would be possible, I´ve been doing some more research an apparently fs uses AFHDS 2A  kind of receives, so I think I was completely wrong assuming any receiver could speak with my i6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the FSi6 (whatever that is) uses an nRF27L01+ as its transmitter, then no - you can't.

The nRF24L01+ chip will *only* communicate with other nRF24L01+ chips.  It contains its own custom protocol within the chip and it can only talk that protocol and no others.